# tagit adding tags when clicking away

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, tag-it

I'm using tagit (http://webspirited.com/tagit/) and really liking it so far.  I've just got one snag to overcome.
If I start typing a tag keyword, change my mind then click elsewhere on the page (so the input loses focus), the tag gets added.  I dont want this to happen.  I want the tag to only be added when the trigger key has been selected - in my case the comma.  Otherwise the last tag (probably partial text) should just sit there until a comma is added.

This is the code I have so far.  Pretty basic implementation, but I dont see a way to prevent the scenario above.

```
 $('#thename').tagit({
      tagSource:, 
      select:true,
      tagsChanged:function (a, b) {
         if(b=='added' || b=='popped'){
            submitForm();
         }
       },
      triggerKeys:new Array('comma')
   });
```

Comment: Should any text be allowed to be tagged or should you only be able to select pre-determined tags?

Comment: Hi. In my current task it's just the pre defined options in the source that I would like. But I may well need to add additional implementations of tagit without any database or array lookup in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a little hack for this one, we'll see how it turns out. I couldn't find anywhere in the API to not add the tag on focus out, so my next solution was to do the following:

-Type a tag
-Click out of the input (so the tag gets added)
-Programatically get the text input and remove the tag

Attempted this with the following code:

```
$("#thename").focusout(function() {
    //Get the input text
    var tagText = $(this).val();

    //Verify input is NOT empty

    //Remove the tag that was just added
    $("#thename").tagit('removeTag', tagText);
```

});

Let me know how this works.

Edit:

Just noticed your comment up there. If you don't want to allow new tags, then add the

```
allowNewTags: false,
```

To your tagit markup in the original code.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I'll give it a try in the morning and get back to you :)

Comment: Hi tymeJV.  Unfortunately the focusout code didn't work for me.  Looking at the DOM I changed $("thename") to $("#thename .tagit-input") as #thename is just the ul.  This catches the text now, but still doesn't work as the tag gets added to the select before firing the focusout code, by which time my page has already started reloading.  Its a puzzler!

Comment: Have you tried adding the allowNewTags: false, in your tagit markup? This should disable unknown tags from being entered.

Comment: Yes thats true. It certainly solves the problem in the question, so I'll mark it as correct, thank you :)  Just thinking for future uses where you can enter any tag but dont want it adding until the trigger key is hit i.e. correct the focus/blur problem.  But I'll worry about that if I face it.  Its pretty minor in that scenario anyway. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Please note that Tag-it! has updated 'removeTag' to 'removeTagByLabel'